# Handing SSIS validation failures

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to implement the SSIS package failure handler. I've added onError Event handler on whole package and failure operation the task where i'm expecting an error in the control flow.

The main task of the package is to pick up some data from the db, 
the error handler is Send Mail Task sending email message with error description.

Now, I'm trying to emulate a common error: I make some changes in the SQL query (for example, set incorrect name for one of the columns) and try to run the package.

What i see is that package fails on validation stage and does not even proceed to execution, saying

```
Error:  SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occured. Error Code 0x80040E14. An OLE DB record is available. Source "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"     
Hresult 0x80040E14 Description "Statement(s) could not be prepared"
Description "The multipart identifier "MyTable.SomeWrongField" could not be bound". 
Error: "OLE DB Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_BROKEN".
```

It doesn't even procceed to execution, failing right after validation.
How to set the error handle so it handles EVERY error, even the issue like this (incorrect sql request)?

Thanks.

Comment: You could always create another event handler either OnTaskFailed or OnPreValidate with a Send Mail Task.

Comment: OnTaskFailed doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Validation error is the SSIS equivalent of a syntax error. There is no opportunity for recovery as the execution is dead in the water. OnTaskFailed and OnError won't catch this type of error (which is one of the reasons we no longer implement error notification from within our packages themselves)

Comment: Do you perform notification in case of these failures anyhow?

Comment: We have the same scenario - how are you implementation error notifications in such a case?